# why no output from file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**why there is no content in the "file object?"**

Tried changing to append and there's content since the second run. What am I missing here?

code below:

```
import random
from io import StringIO

class WriteMyStuff(object):

    def __init__(self, writer):
        self.writer = writer

    def write(self):
        write_text = "this is a silly message\n"
        self.writer.write(write_text)

fh = open('test.txt', 'w')
w1 = WriteMyStuff(fh)
w1.write()
fh.close

sioh = StringIO()
w2 = WriteMyStuff(sioh)
w2.write()

print("file object: ", open('test.txt', 'r').read())
print("StringIO object:", sioh.getvalue())
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because you forgot to call the `close` method properly in line 17. You called it like an attribute where it needs to be called with the parenthesis `.close()`. Here's, the fixed version:

```py
import random
from io import StringIO


class WriteMyStuff(object):
    def __init__(self, writer):
        self.writer = writer

    def write(self):
        write_text = "this is a silly message\n"
        self.writer.write(write_text)


fh = open("test.txt", "w")
w1 = WriteMyStuff(fh)
w1.write()
fh.close()

sioh = StringIO()
w2 = WriteMyStuff(sioh)
w2.write()


print("file object: ", open("test.txt", "r").read())
print("StringIO object:", sioh.getvalue())
```

This will print out:

```
file object:  this is a silly message

StringIO object: this is a silly message
```

This code still has one subtle bug, it hasn't closed the second file handler object in the line before the last line.

You can use `contextmanages` if you don't want to handle closing the file handlers manually. Consider this example:

```
import random
from io import StringIO


class WriteMyStuff(object):
    def __init__(self, writer):
        self.writer = writer

    def write(self):
        write_text = "this is a silly message\n"
        self.writer.write(write_text)


with open("test.txt", "w") as fh:
    w1 = WriteMyStuff(fh)
    w1.write()


sioh = StringIO()
w2 = WriteMyStuff(sioh)
w2.write()


with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    print("file object: ", f.read())
    
print("StringIO object:", sioh.getvalue())
```

The `with` block takes care of closing the file handler after you go out of scope.